# Помогите пожалуйста с php

Tags: php

вот код

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);// чекает ошибки
$v=$randomc==$randomx ;
$randomx=mt_rand(1,6); // от одного до шести 
$randomc=mt_rand(1,6); //от одного до шести 
if (($randomx>$randomc)){
    echo "победил игрок 1  $randomc , а игрок 2 проиграл $randomx ";}
else (($randomc<$randomx));{
    echo "победил игрок 2  $randomx , а игрок 1 проиграл $randomc ";}
    elseif ((v));{
        echo "ничья, у вас одинаковые цифры $randomx у 1 и $randomc у воторого";}
      exit();
?>
```

вот ссылка на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/itbEcw)

я тут  новичек и не могу понять в чем проблема,почему выдает ошибку в строке `elseif` ?

Comment: Приведите Ваш вопрос в порядок, понятно оформленного кода нет, а ссылка не работает.

Comment: условия правильно оформлять так: `if (CONDITION) { BODY; } elseif (ANOTHER_CONDITION) { ANOTHER_BODY; } else { ELSE_BODY; }` а теперь сравните с вашим кодом. Кстати, ideone вам же показал где ошибка. И еще: `$v = $randomc == $randomx;` вам не кажется, что здесь что-то не так?

Comment: У вас немного ахтунг. Смотрите [примеры](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.elseif.php) использования elseif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elseif ((v));{` здесь есть несколько проблем:

1. elseif сам по себе должен идти до else, т.е.

---

```
 if (условие1) {
    действия
    }

elseif (условие2, когда не сработало условие1) {
    действия
    }

else{
    действия, которые выполнятся, когда ни одно из перечисленных выше условий не сработало
    }
```

2. `v` - без знака `$`, а значит, что это не переменная, а константа, которую заранее нигде не объявили.
3. после `elseif($v)` стоит `;`, что означает, что на этом инструкции закончились. Надо убрать `;` и все заработает

p.s. еще проблема будет с присваиванием `$v=$randomc==$randomx ;` в самом начале: здесь в переменных `$randomc` и `$randomx` еще нет значений. Надо эту строку передвинуть после присваивания и я бы это взял в скобки, как то так:

```
$randomx=mt_rand(1,6); // от одного до шести 
$randomc=mt_rand(1,6); //от одного до шести 
$v=($randomc==$randomx);
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас немного избыточен код и некоторые ошибки в синтаксисе

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);// чекает ошибки

$randomx = mt_rand(1, 6); // от одного до шести
$randomc = mt_rand(1, 6); // от одного до шести

if ($randomx > $randomc) {
  echo "победил игрок 1 $randomc, а игрок 2 проиграл $randomx ";
} elseif ($randomc < $randomx) {
  echo "победил игрок 2 $randomx, а игрок 1 проиграл $randomc ";
} else {
  echo "ничья, у вас одинаковые цифры $randomx у 1 и $randomc у второго";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ))))))))))